# Basic update database table using php question

Tags: php, mysql

I seem to be missing something quite fundamental here and yet my code doesn't seem to be any different to any of the numerous online tutorials that I have looked at.
What I would like is for someone to look at this and say....Oh you have forgotten to...etc;

This is what I have on a separate update page which is intended to perform the update then cycle back to the main admin page:

```
require_once('../Connections/MyConn.php');
$sql_statement = "UPDATE skyscrapers SET ";
$sql_image = "Ad_image = '" . $_REQUEST['image'] . "', ";
$sql_expire = "Ad_Expires = '" . $_REQUEST['expire'] . "'";

$result = mysql_query($sql_statement . $sql_image . $sql_expire . " WHERE Ad_ID=" . $_REQUEST['ADID']);
if (!$result) {
  echo("<p>Error performing query: " . mysql_error() . "</p>");
  exit();
} 

mysql_close ($MyConn); 
header("location:Admin_skyscrapers.php");
```

However when I run this I get the following error:-

**"Error performing query: No database selected"**

Well, haven't I selected the database in the connection script which already works everywhere else?

I realise the code isn't very pretty and I am being naughty using the url to pass variables at the moment - I do promise to change this when I get it to work :)

So, any pointers would be helpful, thanks in advance.

Edit to add...

This is the connection script with the sensitive stuff redacted:-

```
# FileName="Connection_php_mysql.htm"
# Type="MYSQL"
# HTTP="true"
$hostname_MyConn = "*************.co.uk";
$database_MyConn = "db**********";
$username_MyConn = "dbo*********";
$password_MyConn = "*****";
$MyConn = mysql_pconnect($hostname_MyConn, $username_MyConn, $password_MyConn) or trigger_error(mysql_error(),E_USER_ERROR);
```

Comment: can you post the code in your `MyConn.php`? and a snippet that is working maybe

Comment: Ok, we understand, that you're naughty, but don't use $_REQUEST['...'], use $_GET['...'], because with $_REQUEST, you can't be sure where exactly the variable comes. http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.request.php

Comment: Make sure you change your code to escape user supplied data ($_REQUEST, $_GET, etc...). You can use `mysql_real_escape_string` http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php

Comment: @PalmTree $_REQUEST can be fine if you understand what it implies

Comment: If I post myConn.php it contains all the username password stuff, and I don't feel comfortable putting that on the internet. Sorry! It's for a website that I didn't build and uses all sorts of code that I don't understand. I did tell the client that I'm really "just" a designer, but they were keen to have me handle it for them so I'm using my basic, leftover knowledge to make the changes that they want.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This may or may not be declared in your MyConn.php but all you need is a line:

```
mysql_select_db($db_name);
```

Where $db_name is the name of your database.

This should come before you attempt to execute the query.

Comment: Thanks for the help. That got rid of the error message, but didn't actually update the table :D

Comment: lol i didnt post this answer because i wanted to see why the rest of hist code was working

Comment: @Andrew Then you likely have some other issue with your code.  I see that you feel uncomfortable posting MyConn.php but what you can do is just remove any sensitive information and then post it.  

Is there a new error you are receiving now?

Comment: Hi Jrod, no, there's no new error - I guess the next thing on list is why it isn't inserting. I will add a version of the connection script in the OP.

Comment: The first idea that comes to mind is that the ID in your where clause does not exist in the database.  This won't throw an error but it also won't update anything.  Verify that your ID does indeed exist.

Comment: User error I'm afraid! I am passing the database values in the url not the values from the submitting form. Thanks for putting up with me :)

Answer (score 1):

For DB select you have to add mysql_select_db(DatabaseName); or 
$dbconn=mysql_select_db($dbname,$MyConn);in MyConn.php

For update in Database you have to use connection variable which is in MyConn.php i.e.$MyConn as follows

```
$result = mysql_query($sql_statement . $sql_image . $sql_expire . " WHERE Ad_ID=" . $_REQUEST['ADID'],$MyConn);
```

or

```
 $result = mysql_query($sql_statement . $sql_image . $sql_expire . " WHERE Ad_ID=" . $_REQUEST['ADID'],$dbconn);
```

respectively

Hope It Helps!!!!!!!